Is my solution correct and prove the following

Evaluate $$A=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x+i}+\frac{\sin x }{x-i}\:\:dx$$

I know that
$\displaystyle\int\frac{\sin x}{x+a}dx=\cos a\cdot \textrm{Si}(x+a)-\sin a\cdot \textrm{Ci}(x+a)$
So
$\displaystyle B=\int\frac{\sin x}{x+i}+\frac{\sin x }{x-i}\:\:dx=\cos (i)\cdot \textrm{Si}(x+i)-\sin (i)\cdot \textrm{Ci}(x+i)+\cos (i)\cdot \textrm{Si}(x-i)-\sin (i)\cdot \textrm{Ci}(x-i)$
I used $\sin(-x)=-\sin (x)$ and $\cos(-x)=\cos(x)$
At $x=\infty$ we will have $x+i\approx x-i\to\infty$ so at $x=\infty$, $B=\pi\cos(i)$
At $x=0$ we will have $B=\sin(i)(\textrm{Ci}(-i)-\textrm{Ci}(i))$ or $B=-i\pi\sin(i)$
So we will have
$A=\pi\cos(i)+\pi i\sin(i)$ 
$A=\pi(\cos(i)+i\sin(i))$
$A=\pi\exp(i\cdot i)$
Hence $$\boxed{A=\frac{\pi}{e}}$$

Now I want to know is my solution correct or not as I think I have used some results that are perhaps used for real numbers only. I also did $x+i=x-i$ at infinity and I'm not sure if this is valid.
Also I want to know how 
$\textrm{Ci}(-i)-\textrm{Ci}(i)=-i\pi$
I was stuck here so I used wolframalpha and was surprised to find a closed form for this expression.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

An alternate simpler solution - here,
$A=\int_0^{\infty}\sin x\left(\frac{1}{x+i}+\frac{1 }{x-i}\right)::dx=2\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x\sin x}{1+x^2}:dx$
